# Multiple Sums Grouped by Two Columns over Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math

Consider a pandas dataframe `X` with this format:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"i": [1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                   "k": [2,3,1,3,3,3,4,4,5,5],
                   "l": [1,1,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,2],
                   "X_ikl": [0,0,1,8,2,4,1,1,2,10]})
display(df)
```

```
    i   k  l  X_ikl
0   1   2  1      0
1   1   3  1      0
2   2   1  1      1
3   2   3  1      8
4   2   3  2      2
5   2   3  3      4
6   3   4  1      1
7   3   4  2      1
8   3   5  1      2
9   3   5  2     10
```

I need to perform the sums

[image: text]

That is,
I want to sum each `X_ikl` multiplied pairwise, grouped by `(i,k)`, such that in the first sum, `k'` does not appear in `(i,k)`, and that in the second sum
`i'` does not appear in `(i,k)`.

Note that `i'` `k'` and `l'` are just another iterations over `i` `k` and `l`, respectively. Variables `i` `k` and `l` will always be ordered, starting with `i`, then `k` and lastly `l` (as they appear in the given dataframe).

Also, `l` is just an inner index for each pair for `(i,k)`, going from `1 ... m_ik`.

Lastly, some pair of indices may not appear, like `(i=1,k=1)`, and those should just be skipped.

The real dataframes will be large, so the method needs to be relatively fast. Iterating with `for loops` is not really an option.

**How can I perform these sums over a pandas dataframe with the format given above, with a relatively fast method?**

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:
For the given datframe, the expected solution for the first sum, for each pair `(i,k)` and total sum, looks something like this:

```
(1,2): (0*0) + (0*8 + 0*2 + 0*10) + (0*1 + 0*1) + (0*2 + 0*10) = 0
(1,3): (0*0) + (0*1 + 0*1) + (0*2 + 0*10) = 0
(2,1): (1*0) + (1*8 + 1*2 + 1*4) + (1*1 + 1*1) + (1*2 + 1*10) = 28
(2,3): (8*1) + ((8*1 + 8*1) + (2*1 + 2*1) + (4*1 + 4*1)) + ((8*2 + 8*10) + (2*2 + 2*10) + (4*2 + 4*10)) = 204
(3,4): ((1*0) + (1*0)) + ((1*1) + (1*1)) + ((1*2 + 1*10) + (1*2 + 1*10)) = 26
(3,5): ((2*0) + (10*0)) + ((2*1) + (10*1)) + ((2*1 + 2*1) + (10*1 + 10*1)) = 36

TOTAL SUM = 0 + 0 + 28 + 204 + 26 + 36 = 294
```

Comment: I would advise to provide the exact expected output, ideally breaking down the computation into the unit operations

Comment: @mozway I'm working on a small example (by hand). I will return with an example solution of the expected output. Thanks.

Comment: How is `m_ik` defined?

Comment: @MichaelButscher ```m_ik``` is the upper limit of ```l``` (and ```l'```), for a given pair of ```(i,k)```. ```m_12 = 1```, ```m_13 = 1```, ```m_23 = 3``` etc. It basically stands for the number of times pair ```(i,k)``` occurs (where the order matters).

Comment: @mozway Updated with an (hopefully correct) expected solution. Hinting you since I saw your beautiful solution to my problem yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some solution code for the first problem, and got the answer 300. I double-checked and it seems right.
The idea is that we can sum the `l` variable for each combination of `i` and `k` by using pd.groupby(), and then summing `X_ik'l` independently of `X_ikl`. We can then get `X_ik'l` by calculating the sum of all rows, and then subtract from that all the values that fail the `k not in (i,k)`-condition for each `k`-values.

```
dfX = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "i": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        "k": [2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
        "l": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2],
        "X_ikl": [0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 10],
    }
)

dfX = dfX.groupby(["i", "k"]).sum().drop("l", axis=1).reset_index()

s = dfX['X_ikl'].sum()
si = dfX.groupby('i')['X_ikl'].sum()
sk = dfX.groupby('k')['X_ikl'].sum()

dfX['summed'] = dfX['k'].map(si).fillna(0).add(dfX['k'].map(sk)).rsub(s)
dfX['ans'] = dfX["summed"] * dfX["X_ikl"]

display(dfX)
print("Answer:", dfX['ans'].sum())
```

To solve the second problem instead, simply exchange `dfX['summed'] = dfX['k'].map(si).fillna(0).add(dfX['k'].map(sk)).rsub(s)` with `dfX['summed'] = dfX['i'].map(sk).fillna(0).add(dfX['i'].map(si)).rsub(s)`.